# mongodb aggregation for finding recent data

Tags: mongodb, find, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a model which looks like

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b975b7ffb8361fa0cdacc41"),
"refid" : 1,
"item" : "xyz1",
"qnid" : 1
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b975b7ffb8361fa0cdacc42"),
"refid" : 1,
"item" : "xyz2",
"qnid" : 2
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b975b7ffb8361fa0cdacc43"),
"refid" : 1,
"item" : "xyz3",
"qnid" : 3
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b975b7ffb8361fa0cdacc44"),
"refid" : 4,
"item" : "xyz4",
"qnid" : 4
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b975b7ffb8361fa0cdacc45"),
"refid" : 4,
"item" : "xyz5",
"qnid" : 5
}
```

here refid is the reference id for the article and qnid is the actually id which holdes the version. i want to fetch all the articles ie refid with recent version data.

i want to get the recent records aggregated by **refid**

article refid 1 has qnid 3 as the recent one. article refid 4 has qnid 5 as the recent one.
ie

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b975b7ffb8361fa0cdacc43"),
"refid" : 1,
"item" : "xyz3",
"qnid" : 3
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b975b7ffb8361fa0cdacc45"),
"refid" : 4,
"item" : "xyz5",
"qnid" : 5
}
```

Please help me how can i do this.
I used aggregate function with sort but it is not giving the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.4.

`$sort` on refid asc and qnid desc.

`$group` by refid  and `$first` with `$$ROOT` to access the whole document.

`$replaceRoot` to promote the data to the top.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {"$sort":{"refid":1,"qnid":-1}},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$refid",
    "data":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. but it is not working for me. im using mongo version v3.6.5 . but im getting    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'replaceRoot'",
    "code" : 40324,
    "codeName" : "Location40324"
} : aggregate failed :

Comment: @user2705938 & veeram `replaceRoot` should be `$replaceRoot`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet ah. Thank you!. Updated.

Comment: it works like the way i wanted.. thank you @Veeram and Anthony

Comment: facing another problem in this. if i want to sort by createdAt along with refid and qnid, sort by createdAt doesnot work, as it is already sorted by refid and qnid. how do i sort the record with all 3?   i tried {"$sort":{"refid":1,"qnid":-1,"createdAt":-1}}, and at the end .sort({"createdAt":-1}) .  How can i sort by date  also?